# Too few arguments to function al tratar de adaptar tutorial para hacer un update

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, update

Uso Codeigniter con php, en un tutorial se hace un crud, yo ya tenía el insert y traté de adaptar el código para hacer un update, pero el código del tutorial llama dos veces a mod del modelo, y en una le pasa sólo 1 argumento. Creo que por eso da el error. ¿Qué debo cambiar en el código para que funcione?

main_model

```
<?php  
 class Main_model extends CI_Model  
 {  
    public function __construct() {
        //llamamos al constructor de la clase padre
        parent::__construct();

        //cargamos la base de datos
        $this->load->database();
    }       

    public function mod($DocIdent, $modificar="NULL", $Nombre, $Apellido, $Direccion, $Telefono, $Estado, $FechaIngreso, $Password){    
         if($modificar=="NULL"){
            $consulta=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cliente WHERE DocIdent=$DocIdent");
            return $consulta->result();
        }else{    
          $consulta=$this->db->query("
              UPDATE tbl_cliente SET Nombre='$Nombre', Apellido='$Apellido',
              Direccion='$Direccion', Telefono='$Telefono', Estado='$Estado', FechaIngreso='$FechaIngreso', Password='$Password' 
              WHERE DocIdent=$DocIdent;
                  ");
          if($consulta==true){
              return true;
          }else{
              return false;
          }  
        }      
    }
```

cliente_buscar (el controlador)

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class cliente_buscar extends CI_Controller{
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->database();
            //llamo o incluyo el modelo
            $this->load->model('main_model');
        }

        //controlador para modificar al que
    //le paso por la url un parametro
    public function mod($DocIdent){
        if(is_numeric($DocIdent)){
          $datos["mod"]=$this->main_model->mod($DocIdent);
          $this->load->view("modificar_view",$datos);

            if($this->input->post("submit")){
                $mod=$this->main_model->mod(
                        $DocIdent,         
                        $this->input->post("submit"),                                       
                        $this->input->post("Nombre"),
                        $this->input->post("Apellido"),
                        $this->input->post("Direccion"),
                        $this->input->post("Telefono"),
                        $this->input->post("Estado"),
                        $this->input->post("FechaIngreso"),
                        $this->input->post("Password")
                        );
                if($mod==true){
                    //Sesion de una sola ejecución
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('correcto', 'Usuario modificado correctamente');
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('incorrecto', 'No se pudo modificar el registro');
                }
                redirect(base_url());
            }
        }else{
            redirect(base_url());
        }

    }
```

formulario_buscar_cliente

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <TITLE></TITLE>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">         
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php /*echo base_url();*/ ?>/css/estilos.css"> 
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/application/views/css/estilos.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                margin:0;   
                color:#6a6f8c;  
                font:600 16px/18px 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
            }

            html {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>    
</head>

<body>
    <br>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li role="presentation" ><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/mostrarInicio">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/mostrarDatos/cliente">Ingresar Cliente </a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" ><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/buscarCliente">Buscar Cliente </a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="cuentaxcliente.php">Cuenta Cliente</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="transaccuenta.php">Transación Cuenta</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/transaccion/IngresarTransaccion">Ingresar Tipo de Transacción</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/transaccion/BuscarTransaccion">Buscar Tipo de Transacción</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/login">Login</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <br><br>    
    <h2>Cliente</h2>
        <?php
        //Si existen las sesiones flasdata que se muestren
            if($this->session->flashdata('correcto'))
                echo $this->session->flashdata('correcto');

            if($this->session->flashdata('incorrecto'))
                echo $this->session->flashdata('incorrecto');
        ?>

<table border="1">   

    <?php
    foreach($ver as $fila){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?=$fila->DocIdent;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$fila->Nombre;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$fila->Apellido;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$fila->Direccion;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$fila->Telefono;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$fila->Estado;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$fila->FechaIngreso;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$fila->Password;?>
            </td>
             <td>
                <a href="<?=base_url("cliente_buscar/mod/$fila->DocIdent")?>">Modificar</a>
                <a href="<?=base_url("cliente_buscar/eliminar/$fila->DocIdent")?>">Eliminar</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    <?php

    }
    ?>
    </table>    
    <br>    




    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>            

</body>
</html>
```

modificar_view

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Modificar Cliente</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Modificar Cliente</h2>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <?php foreach ($mod as $fila){ ?>
            <input type="text" name="docIdent" value="<?=$fila->DocIdent?>"/>
            <input type="text"  name="nombre" value="<?=$fila->Nombre?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" value="<?=$fila->Apellido?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="direccion" value="<?=$fila->Direccion?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="telefono" value="<?=$fila->Telefono?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="estado" value="<?=$fila->Estado?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="fechaIngreso" value="<?=$fila->FechaIngreso?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="password" value="<?=$fila->Password?>"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modificar"/>
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
        <a href="<?=base_url()?>">Volver</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El eliminar si te funciona?

Comment: No lo he implementado aún, @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav